Weird behavior of Reduce
Reduce[y >= Cos[x] && y <= Sin[x] && x >= 1 && x <= 6, {x, y}] returns the following:

Two things are here: cosine and sine are rewritten in terms of tangent of half-angle and the point $\pi$ is separated. Why is that?
How to get simplified region?
When I try to use Simplify (Reduce[y >= Cos[x] && y <= Sin[x] && x >= 1 && x <= 6, {x,  y}] // Simplify), I get the following:

How to get rid of $\pi$ and get the region as (xrange, yrange) pairs?

if you add Reals to Reduce command, you get simpler answer. (1 <= x < 2 π - 2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] &&     Cos[x] <= y <= Sin[x]) || (x == 2 π - 2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] &&     y == -Sin[2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]]])

Try Reduce[(Cos[x] <= y <= Sin[x]) \[And] (6 >= x >= 1), {x, y},    Reals] // FullSimplify

See this Wikipedia page for the 1st question.

The quick answer about Pi: Singular points (of Tan[x/2] in this case) are separated out. -- To add to @A.Kato's point, Tan[x/2] is replaced by a variable, thereby reducing the principal system to rational functions in two variables, instead of dealing with s = Sin[x] and c = Cos[x] separately under a constraint c^2+s^2==1.

In  case this is what is wanted:
p = {x, Sin[x]} /. Solve[Tan[x] == 1 && 0 < x < 2 Pi, x];
e1 = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[p]}];

i = ImplicitRegion[
   Cos[x] < y < Sin[x], {{x, p[[1, 1]], p[[2, 1]]}, {y, -1, 1}}];
e2 = RegionPlot[i];
Show[e1, e2]
i


